# Default precision of number datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column in my Oracle table that is of NUMBER datatype.The length of the column's max value is 39 digits long.I thought if the precision is not specified ,by default precision is 38.If so,how can it store a value that is 39 digits long?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle can store/represent numbers up to 39 digits, but it **guarantees** only 38 digits of precision. This is why it only allows you to specify precision up to 38, and most of the documentation only says "38" and doesn't even mention "39".

As far as I can tell, without being an expert in any way, Oracle doesn't explain WHY this is. But I don't think it's hard to speculate. This must have something to do with `power(2, 128)` being a number with 39 digits. I believe Oracle can handle numbers up to `power(2, 128)` - so SOME 39 digit numbers (below that value) can be handled properly, but numbers above that can't, especially if you start doing arithmetic with them. Since Oracle treats numbers as if they were in base 10 (which it can only do in software - in hardware everything is bits), it just states that precision can be "up to 38" (guaranteed), so it doesn't have to explain anything beyond that. But you can, in fact, store 39 digit numbers - just don't expect the 39th digit to be accurate. Sometimes it will be, but sometimes it won't.

EDIT:

Looking again at your question... If your column was defined as `NUMBER(38)` or `NUMBER(38, 0)`, then the length would indeed be bounded at 38. Your column must have been defined as `NUMBER` (without specifying precision), which Oracle expands to `NUMBER(*)`. Or, perhaps, the column was defined as `NUMBER(*)`, or `INT`, `INTEGER`, or `NUMBER(*, 0)` - all are mapped to `NUMBER(*, 0)`. The documentation may say that that's "the same as" `NUMBER(38)` or `NUMBER(38, 0)` respectively, but in reality it isn't - it's what you saw, and what I explained.

For practical purposes though, if you only want to use documented features of the language, you should treat your column **as if** precision was limited by 38, even though in reality the numbers may be stored with more significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind numbers you need storage. But a trick is do / 100, or /1000 before save.. and when you retrieve a data, you do *100, or *1000.

I hope it's useful.

Comment: A trick for doing what? How is your answer related to the question? Which was, if this isn't very clear to you: Why is the length of a numeric column shown as 39, when Oracle says maximum precision is 38? In what manner does your answer address a "WHY..." question?

Comment: @mathguy ok.. i explain.. One time I needed storaged long number, like that 0,0000019299292.. doing 0,0000019299292 * 10000 = 0,019299292 did not lost number and its shorter

Comment: I understand why you would use that strategy. What I don't understand is how that answers the OP's question in any way. He didn't ask for "HOW can I do <whatever>" - he just wanted to understand why a number column shows data length 39, when Oracle says numbers can only have length 38. The fact that you have used that idea yourself doesn't mean it answers the OP's question, which is totally unrelated.